# How do I open new tab from current window?

Tags: selenium

I used below code to open the new tab..but it is not working..
can someone help, is there any other way to do this?

```
Robot rr= new Robot();
    rr.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rr.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    rr.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rr.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    Set<String> allWindows=driver.getWindowHandles();`enter code here`
    System.out.println(allWindows);
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    driver.switchTo().window(list.get(1));
    driver.get("url");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript executor for opening a new tab in the same window.Please follow the approach mentioned below:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.open();");
```

I have tried it on my MAC machine and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
String parentWindowHandler=driver.getWindowHandle();// Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
  subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // Switch to new tab
```